# Having issues with Selenium scrapes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am just learning selenium basics (ver 4.11.2), and I am continuing to get errors while I executing my code. I am trying to scrape a dealerships used car inventory, however when no matter what class I used in the element.find_element_by_class_name, I get an error that 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_class_name'. What am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
# Set up the web driver (make sure you have ChromeDriver installed)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.freedomfordsales.ca/vehicles/used/?st=price,asc&view=grid&sc=used"
driver.get(url)
vehicle_data = []
# Locate the HTML elements that contain vehicle information
vehicle_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("vehicle-card__full-details")
for element in vehicle_elements:
vehicle_name = element.find_element_by_class_name("vehicle-card__title mb-xs").text.strip()
vehicle_price = element.find_element_by_class_name("srp__dealer-price").text.strip()
vehicle_data.append([vehicle_name, vehicle_price])
# Close the web driver
driver.quit()
# Write the data to a CSV file
csv_filename = "vehicle_data.csv"
with open(csv_filename, mode="w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(["Vehicle Name", "Price"])
for data in vehicle_data:
csv_writer.writerow(data)
print(f"CSV file '{csv_filename}' created successfully.")
```

I have tried to use different class names but I cant seem to select the correct one to scrape the data

Comment: Please provide your version of Selenium so that we can assist you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Selenium `4.11.2` and methods `find_elements_by_something` were removed in Selenium `4.3.0`.

[Reference](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES)

You should use method with syntax `find_element(by, locator)` instead.

In you case:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# your code
vehicle_elements = driver.find_elements(By,CLASS_NAME, 'vehicle-card__full-details')
```